# Gift idea for breastfeeding mom

Tags: breastfeeding

Can any breastfeeding mothers (or former breastfeeding mothers) suggest a soothing Mother's Day gift?  I got my wife and mother of 2 some clothes and other things already but I wanted to throw in something well 'er soothing and thoughtful... like lanolin or a [Boppy](http://www.boppy.com/) (she already has both).

I would ask her but that would defeat the 'gift' aspect.  I would ask coworkers but that would be somewhat creepy.

Any suggestions for thoughtful stocking stuffers for a breast feeding mom?

Comment: My wife just wanted wine and sushi.  Could you do a night out with a babysitter watching the kids?

Comment: An iPad. It'll give her something to do while she feeds.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: No idea.  Have an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, off the top of my head --

A nice reusable cup (like the insulated coldcups that come with straws), so that she always has something to drink while she's nursing. You can fill it with the individual packs of drink mixes in her favorite flavors.

A nursing necklace -- something that she can wear had have it be pretty, and that the baby can play with while he or she nurses. There are some REALLY nice ones out there.

Comment: +1 for cup. BIG cup. With a lid and a straw. My partner's currently breastfeeding, and a cup that she can drop from a short height without spilling everywhere is a godsend. Especially as she's stuck for 20 minutes/half an hour, unable to move, with water being drained out of her by our adorable spawn.

Answer (score 3):

This is a BIG gift, the kind that's probably birthday and Mother's Day, but I'd recommend a smartphone/iPod Touch or smaller e-Reader. An internet/reading device that can be used one handed is a real sanity-saver.

I see Dave Clarke above suggested an iPad, but I don't know how well they work one handed, whereas I happen to know the keyboard kindle works really well.

Comment: My wife loved the Kindle I got her while she was breastfeeding---she normally doesn't read much, but she even read War & Peace while breastfeeding (!)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a stocking filler, but a rocking nursing chair and footstool is likely to be appreciated.

If money is tight then look on eBay, they can be had cheap in good condition second-hand (here at least).

Answer (score 2):

Stork Craft Hoop Glider and Ottoman will be the best gift for breastfeeding moms. A place for them to sit comfortably and nurse her baby. This makes her breastfeeding life easier and more comfortable.